# Where is Text alignment option for text view in the latest version of Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie here and trying to dive in into android development with android studio.

I was watching a video on udemy on their intro to android development tutorial and I noticed that the android studio **(version 3.1.3 running on mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6**) does not have any **textAlignment** option for **textView**.

Below are some screenshots to show you exactly what I mean:

[image: **textAlignment** option in udemy video]

[image: Can't find any **textAlignment** option on the latest version of Android Studio]

[image: My Android Studio version]

So yeah, I'm really confused about this and I've been trying to google any answer for this to no avail. Isn't the option supposed to be there? Forgive me if it turns out that I made a stupid mistake or something, I'm a total beginner when it comes to this, just trying to learn.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textAlignment` was introduced in **api level 17**, so you can not see it there, if your **`minSdkVersion`** is greater than **17**.

You can specify `gravity` in `TextView`. If you use `textAlignment = "textEnd"` then you have to specify `gravity` also.

So i suggest you **use just `gravity`** for same purpose. If you still want enter `textAlignment` then you can type in text editor of xml. There you will see suggestion of `textAlignment`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using android 3.1.3 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6
I don't know about UI options. But, you definitely can add it in the XML like,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

You are editing it in the design view right now. Switch it to the text part of activity_main.xml.
Hope this works for you.